# Testing Unsupervised Machine Learning Algorithms

Tags: testing, machine-learning

All over the Internet, I can see applications of supervised and unsupervised Machine Learning Algorithms but no one is talking about maintaining the quality of machine learning apps.
The recent analysis on how to test unsupervised machine learning algorithms brought up these points:

1) Cross-validation Testing: Dataset is divided into equal folds(parts) and all folds except the one are used as training dataset and later is used as test dataset 
 
Few more options around using test and training dataset.

Are there more effective ways of testing unsupervised ML algorithms where the output is uncertain?

Comment: Assessing the quality of unsupervised machine learning algorithms is problematic since there exists no external criteria (=unsupervised). If you are not targetting a specific application (clustering, dimensionality reduction,...), this question is too broad to be answered. Further, crossvalidation is most used evaluation of supervised machine learning algorithms.

Comment: I recommend asking this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of algorithm (and choosen distance) you used, you can still try to look if the variance between group and the variance within group is changing a lot.

If your algorithm is still as good as when you built it, the variance between and the variance within should not change that much. If the variance between shrink (or the reverse), it mean groups are not as well separated as before by your algorithm.

The second thing you can try is to keep some observations (that you know were well classified) to see if they are still in the same group once you retrained your algorithm. If not, it doesn't mean your algorithm is wrong, but you can send an alert in this case to look deeper.